# Using SAR to monitor free disk space data

Tags: disk

Is there a way to make `sar` (from `sysstat`) collect free disk space data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe this post is old, however, you can get the disk space with the current version (sysstat-11.1.1)

Example:

```
[root@ipboss-linux ~]# sar -F 1 1
Linux 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 (ipboss-linux.qualif.fr)    09/23/2014      _x86_64_        (8 CPU)

11:21:16 AM  MBfsfree  MBfsused   %fsused  %ufsused     Ifree     Iused    %Iused FILESYSTEM
11:21:17 AM      4974      4869     49.47     54.55    441591    199257     31.09 /dev/sda3
11:21:17 AM        65        32     32.71     37.87     25649        39      0.15 /dev/sda1
11:21:17 AM    215269      1278      0.59      5.67  14068929     13119      0.09 /dev/sda2
```

Comment: Note that (according to https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/blob/master/CHANGES) this was added in 10.1.6

Answer (score 2):

No, it can not. My guess on the reason is that it isn't necessarily tied directly to performance, at least not in a way that makes sense in polled intervals.

[munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) is an example of a tool that will do this, but it writes to RRD files, which can not be in a human readable form from the command line.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to add a custom measure to the data collected by `sar`, or would it be better to create a parallel system to collect that? Hmmmm!

Answer (score 0):

Run sadc with the XDISK option and it collects filesystem usage data.